# How do I convert a base64 image?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to use the "convert" command-line tool from ImageMagick.  I have a base64 encoded png file and I need to convert it to another format.  I am looking at [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/) and a [forum discussion](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=26918) which suggests that I should be able to use this syntax:

```
convert inline:file.txt file.jpg
```

But when I do this, I get this error message:

```
convert: corrupt image `file.txt' @ error/constitute.c/ReadInlineImage/910.
```

What am I doing wrong?  How do I get convert to read a base64 image file?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Updated Answer** - now that I understand it better myself :-)

Basically, you can base64 encode an image using `openssl` like this:

```
openssl enc -base64 -in image.png > image.b64
```

However, if you want `ImageMagick` to be able to read it, you need a small header at the start, to tell `ImageMagick` what follows. The header must contain:

```
data:image/png;base64,
```

followed by your base64 encoded data generated using the `openssl` command above. So, depending on what features your shell has, you could do it like this with a compound statement in `bash`:

```
{ echo "data:image/png;base64,"; openssl enc -base64 -in input.png; } > image.b64
```

or like this in Windows:

```
echo data:image/png;base64,         > image.b64
openssl enc -base64 -in image.png  >> image.b64
```

Once you have the image in that format, you can then proceed to process it with `ImageMagick` like this:

```
convert inline:image.b64 result.png
```

For those who use this in css, add `-A` flag to output in one line

```
openssl enc -base64 -A -in image.png > image.b64
```

**Original Answer**

After MUCH experimenting, I can do it!!! :-)

Start with Eric's (@emcconville) setup:

```
# For example
convert rose: rose.png
# Create base64 file
openssl enc -base64 -in rose.png -out rose.txt
```

and now add this mess as the last line:

```
{ echo "data:image/png;base64,"; cat rose.txt; } | convert inline:- out.jpg
```

I guess the `data:image/png;base64,` is not present in the base64 file created by `openssl` so I create a compound statement that sends that plus the file to `stdin` of `ImageMagick`.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated answer**

From ImageMagick [format docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php)...

> The inline image look similar to `inline:data:;base64,/9j/4AAQSk...knrn//2Q==`. If the inline image exceeds 5000 characters, reference it from a file (e.g. `inline:inline.txt`).

This hints at two "gotcha" when using the inline format. First any standard base64 whitespace (unix line break) should be removed such that all information would be on one line. And second, that any data above 5000 characters should be read from a file buffer.

```sh
# Copy data to new file, striping line-breaks & adding INLINE header. (Please advise better sed/awk.)
cat file.txt | tr -d "\r\n" | awk '{print "data:image/png;base64,"$1}' > file.inline
# Read file as expected
convert inline:file.inline file.jpg
```

**Original (not really correct) answer**

The "corrupt image" message tells me that there may be whitespace in the base64 file. If so, the [tr](/questions/tagged/tr) utility would work.

```sh
# For example
convert rose: rose.png
# Create base64 file
openssl enc -base64 -in rose.png -out rose.txt
# Read inline & data from stdin -- after stripping whitespace
cat rose.txt | tr -d "\r\n" | convert inline:data:- out.jpg
```

Comment: I'm afraid that gave me basically the same error: "convert: corrupt image `data:-' @ error/constitute.c/ReadInlineImage/910."  I don't see any whitespace in the original file other than the line ending (unix).

Comment: Can you recreate the same message from a new image?

Comment: Yes, I get it with any base64 image I use.

Comment: I can't understand how that syntax is supposed to be used, or else it simply doesn't work.  Can't find any explicit examples online of how to read a base64 image file with convert.

Comment: Okay, updated answer. @MarkSetchell Please feel free to simplify as needed.

Comment: I think we have pretty much both come to the same thing at the same time! You modify the file and rewrite it with the header in, and I create a compound statement that dynamically adds it into the stream that IM sees. It's horses for courses! I think the linebreaks are a red herring actually - I don't strip them.

Comment: Awesome, you got it!  I agree with Mark, I didn't need to strip the linebreaks.  Thank you guys for figuring this out when the provided documentation was inadequate.

Comment: Very hard to decide whether to credit emcconville or @Mark Setchell with the answer.  I finally gave it to Mark because of the straightforward comment "if you want ImageMagick to be able to read it, you need a small header at the start."  If only ImageMagick themselves had seen fit to include that piece of the explanation in the first place.